# Generate combinations of a given sequence without recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x

1. Given an array of unique numbers find the combinations
2. Doing a shallow copy in the code to avoid changes to the passed obj by reference
3. This has a run time of \$O(n \times \text{#ofcombinations})\$ - can this be done better -- iteratively and easy to understand

```
import copy
def gen_combinations(arr): # 
    res = [[]]
    for ele in arr:
        temp_res = []
        for combination in res:
            temp_res.append(combination)
            new_combination = copy.copy(combination)
            new_combination.append(ele)
            temp_res.append(new_combination)
            res = copy.copy(temp_res)
        
    return res
```

Comment: Step 2 says "Doing a deep copy...", but `copy.copy()` does a shallow copy, which is fine in this case.

Comment: thanks for catching that @RootTwo, edited the description

Answer (score 12):

First, a side note. What you call `combination` is usually called `subset`.

In a set of \$n\$ elements an average length of a subset is \$\dfrac{n}{2}\$. That is, generating a single subset takes \$O(n)\$ time. You cannot get a time complexity better than \$O(n2^n)\$.

The space complexity is a different matter. If you indeed need all the subset at the same time, then again the space complexity cannot be better than \$O(n2^n)\$. On the other hand, if you want one subset at a time, consider converting your function to a generator, which would `yield` subsets one at a time.

A more or less canonical way of generating subsets uses the 1:1 mapping of subsets and numbers. Each number `a` in the \$[0, 2^n)\$ range uniquely identifies subset of \$n\$ elements (and vice versa). Just pick the elements at the position where `a` has a bit set.

All that said, consider

```
def generate_subsets(arr):
    n = len(arr)
    for a in range(2 ** n):
        yield [arr[i] for i in range(n) if (a & (1 << i)) != 0]
```

Comment: Just a note, one can always iterate a finite generator and fill an array with all the results. So it actually feels more flexible to do that way even if now, you need them all at once.